# Issues with PayPal IPN Script

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal, paypal-ipn

Okay, so I was recently working on my own auto-payment sort of system using the IPN for PayPal. I struggled for a few hours and came up with what is below. Although my payment goes through to my alternate paypal email the payment is marked as failed. What it should do is when it comes back verified insert the transaction details into the database for use later on. Whether that be order references or just showing the buyer that their payment was successful etc. How I use it is by going to domain.com/pay.php?id= and then the id of what I was attempting to purchase.

This is the main class which I call "pay.php"

```
require_once('class_ipn.php');
$p = new paypal_class;
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    Site::Stop('/login');
} 

$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';           
$this_script = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if(empty($_GET['action'])) { $_GET['action'] = 'process'; }

switch ($_GET['action']) 
{    
    case 'process':
    {
        switch($_GET['id'])
        {
            case 1:
            {           
                $cost = '0.01';
                $name = 'Name #1';
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {           
                $cost = '6.00';
                $name = 'Name #2';
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {           
                $cost = '5.00';
                $name = 'Name #3';
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {           
                $cost = '60.00';
                $name = 'Name #4';
                break;
            }
        }

        $p->add_field('business', '');
        $p->add_field('return', 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $p->add_field('custom', $_SESSION['id']);
        $p->add_field('cancel_return', 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
        $p->add_field('item_number', $_GET['id']);
        $p->add_field('item_name', $name);
        $p->add_field('amount', $cost);

        $p->submit_paypal_post();           
        break;
    }

    case 'ipn':
    {

        if ($p->validate_ipn()) 
        {   
            CMS::$MySql->Insert('purchases', array(
                'transaction_id' => $p->ipn_data['txn_id'],
                'user_id' => $p->ipn_data['custom'],
                'package_id' => $p->ipn_data['item_number'],
                'time' => time(),
                'status' => 'Pending',
                'payment_method' => 'PayPal'
            ));
        }
      break;
    }
}
```

This is the other file that is called on pay.php incase you need it for reference. But, I'm still not sure as to why it's marking them as failed to even begin with.

```
class paypal_class
{
    var $last_error;
    var $ipn_log;
    var $ipn_log_file;
    var $ipn_response;
    var $ipn_data = array();
    var $fields = array();


    function paypal_class()
    {
        $this->paypal_url   = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->last_error   = '';
        $this->ipn_log_file = 'ipn_results.log';
        $this->ipn_log      = true;
        $this->ipn_response = '';
        $this->add_field('rm', '2');
        $this->add_field('cmd', '_xclick');
    }

    function add_field($field, $value)
    {
        $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
    }

    function submit_paypal_post()
    {
        echo "<html>\n";
        echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title>";
        echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
        echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
        echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
        echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
        echo "action=\"" . $this->paypal_url . "\">\n";
        foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
        }
        echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
        echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";
        echo "</body></html>\n";
    }

    function validate_ipn()
    {
        $url_parsed  = parse_url($this->paypal_url);
        $post_string = '';

        foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
            $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
            $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
        }
        $post_string .= "cmd=_notify-validate";


        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$fp) {

            $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
            $this->log_ipn_results(false);
            return false;

        } else {
            fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
            fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }

            fclose($fp);
        }

        if (eregi("VERIFIED", $this->ipn_response)) {
            $this->log_ipn_results(true);
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
            $this->log_ipn_results(false);
            return false;
        }

    }

    function log_ipn_results($success)
    {
        if (!$this->ipn_log)
            return;
        $text = '[' . date('m/d/Y g:i A') . '] - ';
        if ($success)
            $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
        else
            $text .= 'FAIL: ' . $this->last_error . "\n";

        $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
        foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key => $value) {
            $text .= "$key=$value, ";
        }

        $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n " . $this->ipn_response;
        $fp = fopen($this->ipn_log_file, 'a');
        fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }

    function dump_fields()
    {
        echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
        echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
            <tr>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
            </tr>";

        ksort($this->fields);
        foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>" . urldecode($value) . "&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        }

        echo "</table><br>";
    }
}
```

Last but not least are the logs it creates from this script.

```
[07/07/2017 4:21 PM] - FAIL: IPN Validation Failed.
IPN POST Vars from Paypal:

IPN Response from Paypal Server:
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: Apache

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: dcg12.slc

Paypal-Debug-Id: 4dceeade1904c

Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

DC: ccg11-origin-www-2.paypal.com

Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2017 20:21:06 GMT

Content-Length: 7

Connection: close

Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=t4-TIdtjrBz8vS57KUToznKW3kNvFvf7eD_Gu_IQla03osxOCn0iGStIefoynQ-a5QdBb47FJMxq2ldNeHFrZ2sF7Z8-0qHCMRLKiPTD_hEOSmwHA3p7p_hmuO6W162Ulf71gGUUETkLoRLjOjTaAm4AWwDYTs6Dq_T9_u9dmbjLwzqn7Tk3AWDoFkp44CUsCwNAmXmDNEwr15NHSGGsG2QJlVRGw-6KNfLLTHfg8XG0vX6DANepNeRsOrTvB-qjNlwIkjFsYu0m46qJ3GtCk1ydMho_N2zE4C-ZBr-eEeshULK7IAFnHwmRxHXRywwzpDCvRVqV1SuEhtGXEiDDjlTAuhmPRIPK3u6h0NapytpGcF1a2479y189PoHui1_0nxWtJlpYMyc1seppCF_Syenmn6SiAj1jfFlTkucUO2AqpDEz5xJb3DB_SdO; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Mon, 05-Jul-2027 20:21:06 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Sun, 07-Jul-2019 20:21:06 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE5.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D854417241%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Ddcg12.slc; Expires=Fri, 07 Jul 2017 20:51:06 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT

Set-Cookie: AKDC=ccg11-origin-www-2.paypal.com; expires=Fri, 07-Jul-2017 20:51:06 GMT; path=/; secure

Set-Cookie: akavpau_ppsd=1499459466~id=63e1479e71581fc5ddb36390f64a0b67; Path=/

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000



INVALID
```

Any help is welcome and very much appreciated. If you have any questions regarding bits or pieces feel free to ask and maybe together we can get to the bottom of this!

Regards,
Jake

Comment: The transaction should work as follows - you create an entry in the database regarding the transaction, display the form for given transaction and redirect the user to PayPal. User commences transaction on PayPal, and in the background your server is contacted via IPN to url, which you should use to find the order you're verifying. User should then be redirected (from PayPal) to a url, where he needs to wait for your server to verify the transaction. Atm you're not passing which order should be verified by IPN, nor are you comparing the values PayPal came back with